# Using an Archos 3G modem with an Acer Iconia tab (Android Honeycomb)

Tags: usb, 3g, acer-iconia-a500

I've recently purchased an Acer Iconia tablet with Android 3.1. Then I adquired an Archos G9 3G USB modem, with the intention of having internet connection on my tablet when not around a wifi (90% of the time for me, sadly). I *thought* using it would be simple, like with a PC: insert the USB modem on the tablet, it recognises it, asks me some questions to configure it and so on.

But no, when I insert the USB modem on my tablet it does **absolutely nothing**. I've searched on the net for instructions about this but haven't found any. Is this USB modem intended for using **only** with Archos tablets? Anyone on my situation?

Answer (score 2):

It's plug-and-play on your PC because the industry has an established standard for driver infrastructure in Windows & OSX. Android isn't as friendly to 3rd party drivers. There's some limited success reported with specific models of 3g dongle - you may need to switch devices. Here's a partial list from [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=14603952):

> - ZTE MF 639 (might need roaming enabled to get data working)
> - Vodafone K3765-H
> - Vodafone K3715
> - Vodafone K3565 / Huawei E160
> - Huawei E169
> - Huawai E170
> - Huawai E171
> - Huawei E173
> - Huawei E1550
> - Huawei E1692
> - Huawei E1750
> - Huawei E1752
> - Huawei E1820
> - HUAWEI K3520
> - HUAWEI K3565 -Rev 2